# Parsing multiline string in C

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I'm trying to parse a file using C language with a format like this:

```
FILE, "CONTENT", PATH
```

So, for example I have an input like this:

```
file.txt, "This is a simple file", /home/user
config.txt, "#Used to do any configurations
             #ID = 'PC1'
             VERSION = 1.25", /etc
```

First, I read a line of the file an put it into buffer, next I do:

```
sscanf(buffer, "%[^,], \"%[^\"]\", %s", name, content, path)
```

But, however I only get correctly single line inputs. Is there a way to force sscanf to accept new lines on CONTENT string?

Comment: "First, I read a line of the file an put it into buffer, next I do:" `sscanf` doesn't see anything after the newline, the buffer doesn't contain the later lines of the item.

Comment: I actually `printf` buffer and it contains every line...

Comment: Ah, so your verbal description was inaccurate. But the scanset format `%[^\"]` _ought_ to accept newlines. What gets stored in `content` for the `config.txt` entry? And can we see more of the code?

Comment: I really don't know why `%[^\"]` doesn't recognize newlines... `config.txt` was just an example. I'm doing a file system simulator (very basic), so I need to store those files in it.

Answer (score 0):

For non-trivial parsing, I would tecommend using Flex and Bison

Comment: Flex on it's own here and a hand-written parser would be fine. It's very *flex* ible. (couldn't resist). In this case all you need is something that splits tokens on the `','` and is string-aware.

Comment: Really? flex/bison for this? It's not necessary even to ini file format.

Comment: It's not necessary even for a real programming language. I found it harder to get the lex/bison specification right than hand-writing my own lexer and parser.

Comment: Flex and Bison are used extensively in persing the config files for many unix daemons. The big advantage over hand parsers is that you are forced to think carefully about the grammar. It also is much less likely to crash if there is an error in the config files than a hand written parser. There is a fairly large amount of up front learning but I think it more than pays off.